# How use str_sub with pipes?

Tags: r

I have a data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  cpf = c('37576865879', '02177190948')
)
```

I try:

```
library(tidyverse)

str_sub(string = df_1$cpf, start = 4, end = 6) <- 'xxx'

#          cpf
#1 375xxx65879
#2 021xxx90948
```

The result is ok. But:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  cpf = c('37576865879', '02177190948')
)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., var = str_sub(string = cpf, start = 4, end = 6) <- "xxx")

#          cpf var
#1 37576865879 xxx
#2 02177190948 xxx
```

Only `x`s appears into `var`. How adjust this last function to get the complete vector?

```
#          cpf         var
#1 37576865879 375xxx65879
#2 02177190948 021xxx90948
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use this in pipes, you have to use `str_sub<-` method which can be used as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_1 %>% mutate(var = `str_sub<-`(cpf, 4, 6, value = 'xxx'))

#         cpf         var
#1 37576865879 375xxx65879
#2 02177190948 021xxx90948
```